# Get list of files from SYSWOW64 from 64 bit process

Tags: powershell, system32, syswow64

I faced with problem during writing of powershell script.
I should copy 3 .dll file to C:\Windows\SYSWOW64 folder from poweshell 64-bit process.
If I use environment variable

```
$systemFolder = [System.Environment]::SystemDirectory
```

So, under 64-bit process on 64 bit system

```
$systemFolder = "C:\Windows\system32"
```

Is any enviroment variable or some construction to get access to SYSWOW64 folder. I came up with such solution, but I think there is more correct solution

```
$targetFolder = [System.Environment]::SystemDirectory
if([Environment]::Is64BitProcess){
$targetFolder = "$env:windir\SYSWOW64"
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem with that solution, but another option for you might be to run your script in a 32bit proccess, you can do this by runnning as a job using [Start-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7) and the RunAs32 parameter.

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {[Environment]::Is64BitProcess} -RunAs32 | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
False

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {[Environment]::Is64BitProcess} | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
True
```

Another option is to use [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder)

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::SystemX86)
C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64
```